# Вернуть картинку в response

Tags: django, response

Пытаюсь вернуть картинку в response (картинка создаётся динамически), далее хочу ее разместить в  как массив байт.

Пытался сделать это через обычный `HttpResponse(bytes, mimetype="text/plain")`, но Джанго ругается на невозможность преобразовать asci-символ в строке. Пробовал так же через `FileResponse(ByteIO(bytes))`, но получил ту же ошибку.

Какие варианты правильно это сделать?

Comment: Ну так картинка это не текст, зачем вы text/plain написали-то?

Comment: @andreymal, думал, при `text/plain` символы передадутся в чистом виде как массив байт, чтобы потом вставить его в `<img src=data:image/png...>`.

Comment: text автоматически означает, что это не массив байт, а массив символов, а картинку естественно нельзя представить в виде массива символов просто так. Если вы хотите передать картинку в виде base64 символов для Data URI, вот предварительно и закодируйте в base64 без всяких там массивов байт, и уже потом получившийся массив символов пихайте в text/plain

Comment: @andreymal , хочу без base64

Comment: Значит не используйте никакого text

Comment: @andreymal , попробовал с "image/jpeg", ошибка почему-то та же

Comment: Та же это какая? Приведите точный текст ошибки в тексте вопроса